# Highcahrts sometimes loads but not always

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

I have a website, the uses highcharts to display some line and pie charts.
And on all pages the pie charts load normally, but the line chart sometimes loads and sometimes it doesn't.

This is my code for loading the highchart:

```
function loadHighChart()
    {
        $(function () {
            $('#highchart').highcharts({
                chart: {

                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Country Statistic'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    useHTML: true,
                    valueDecimals: 2,
                    valuePrefix: '',
                    valueSuffix: ' (Mt)  '
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: DataYear,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Over years'
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {

                    title: {
                        text: 'Value'
                    },
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Consumption',
                    data: DataConsumption
                },
                    {
                        name: 'Production',
                        data: DataProduction
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Import',
                        data: DataImport
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Export',
                        data: DataExport
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Where are `DataYear`, `DataConsumption`, `DataProduction`, `DataImport` and `DataExport` being generated? I'd bet thats the issue. Any errors in the console? Also the ready handler in the function can be removed.

Comment: DataYear, DataConsumption, DataProduction, DataImport and DataExport are global variables, that have data in it. I used console.log to check. So it's not that. Because the same data is used to load the table below the chart, and it always shows.

Comment: I guess that data comes from backend? If this is AJAX, then the data may be problem. However if the same is displayed in the HTML table, then I guess your format sometimes isn't properly - do you have any error in JS console? Maybe your values are strings, while should be numbers etc.

Comment: Yes, the data comes from backend. I checked my console, the only error I get is for some images, that have nothing to do with charts. As for the format the variables, are being passed as numbers, I checked it as well.

Comment: I would suggest trying with the variables loaded as the direct data and make sure that works first. If that works, you need to find out what the difference between hard coded values and variable-populated values are.  Post the output of those variables here if you don't find your answer.

Comment: I tried hard coding the values. And even then it doesn't load the chart every time. I'm thinking it might be due to a large number of charts being loaded. I have 2 pie charts, that load ok, above the table,  but this line charts is giving me problems.

Comment: This is how it is supposed to look like  http://postimg.org/image/xml4sgyad/

Answer (score 0):

The answer was so simple. I had 2 ajax calls, one that load the char and one that load the table below it. And the problem was that the div for the chart was located inside the div that table data rewrites ones it gets called so it would only show the chart it the table loads first and chart second. So I just moved the chart div outside the tables div. :D